# Deleted object from JPA/EclipseLink re-appears in the database

Tags: jpa, entity, refresh, eclipselink

I have a Java EE application with EclipseLink/JPA entities communicating with my PostgreSQL database. Everything seemed to work fine but lately I notice more and more strange behaviours  with my entities so I need your help to figure out what settings and/or bits of code are wrong...

I have one main issue :sometimes (that's a bad start), when I delete an object through my web app, the object is well deleted in my database (I see it) but when I refresh the app, the deleted object suddenly re-appears (in the app + in the database !) so I guess there is a problem of managed entities behind this ?!

For example, I have an entity "Project" which has a list of "Analysis" and I got this problem when deleting a analysis from a project. It first gets deleted (also in the DB) but when I reopen the project the analysis reappears !

Here is my class Project :

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the projet database table.
 * 
*/
@Entity
@Table(name="projet")
public class Projet implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_projet", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer idProjet;

@Column(name="nom_projet", nullable=false, length=50)
@OrderAttribute(lang=Language.BOTH)
@ShowParameter(position=10)
@IdentifierName(lang=Language.BOTH)
private String nomProjet;

@Column(name="projet_public", nullable=false)
private Boolean projetPublic;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Analyse
@OneToMany(mappedBy="projet", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})//orphanRemoval=true, 
private Set<Analyse> analyses;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Utilisateur the creator of the project
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_utilisateur", nullable=false)
@ShowParameter(position=20)
private Utilisateur utilisateur;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to ProjetUtilDroit
@OneToMany(mappedBy="projet", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<ProjetUtilDroit> projetUtilDroits;


public Projet() {
}

public Integer getIdProjet() {
    return this.idProjet;
}

public void setIdProjet(Integer idProjet) {
    this.idProjet = idProjet;
}

public String getNomProjet() {
    return this.nomProjet;
}

public void setNomProjet(String nomProjet) {
    this.nomProjet = nomProjet;
}

public Boolean getProjetPublic() {
    return projetPublic;
}

public void setProjetPublic(Boolean projetPublic) {
    this.projetPublic = projetPublic;
}

public Set<Analyse> getAnalyses() {
    return this.analyses;
}

public void setAnalyses(Set<Analyse> analyses) {
    this.analyses = analyses;
}

public Utilisateur getUtilisateur() {
    return this.utilisateur;
}

public void setUtilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur) {
    this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
}

public Set<ProjetUtilDroit> getProjetUtilDroits() {
    return this.projetUtilDroits;
}

public void setProjetUtilDroits(Set<ProjetUtilDroit> projetUtilDroits) {
    this.projetUtilDroits = projetUtilDroits;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof Projet){
        Projet project = (Projet) o;
        return (project.idProjet == this.idProjet) || (project.nomProjet.equalsIgnoreCase(this.nomProjet));
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Here is my class Analysis (Analyse in French) :

```
/**
* The persistent class for the analyz database table.
* 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="analyz")
public class Analyse implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_analyse", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer idAnalyse;

@Column(name="nom_analyse", nullable=false, length=50)
@OrderAttribute(lang = Language.BOTH)
private String nomAnalyse;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Projet
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="id_projet", nullable=false)
private Projet projet;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Scenario
@OneToMany(mappedBy="analyse", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})//orphanRemoval=true, 
private Set<Scenario> scenarios;

public Analyse() {
}

public Integer getIdAnalyse() {
    return this.idAnalyse;
}

public void setIdAnalyse(Integer idAnalyse) {
    this.idAnalyse = idAnalyse;
}

public String getNomAnalyse() {
    return this.nomAnalyse;
}

public void setNomAnalyse(String nomAnalyse) {
    this.nomAnalyse = nomAnalyse;
}

public Projet getProjet() {
    return this.projet;
}

public void setProjet(Projet projet) {
    this.projet = projet;
}


public Set<Scenario> getScenarios() {
    return this.scenarios;
}

public void setScenarios(Set<Scenario> scenarios) {
    this.scenarios = scenarios;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof Analyse){
        Analyse a = (Analyse) o;
        return (this.idAnalyse == a.idAnalyse) || (a.getProjet().equals(this.getProjet()) && (this.nomAnalyse.equalsIgnoreCase(a.nomAnalyse)));
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

And I coded a generic DAO for all the classical functions like create/update/delete. Here is my code :

```
  public class BasicDAO<T extends Serializable> implements IDao<T> {

/** The entity class. */
private Class<T> entityClass;
/**
 * The entity manager factory
 */
protected EntityManagerFactory emf;
/**
 * Instantiates a new abstract dao.
 */
public BasicDAO(Class<T> c) {
    entityClass = c;
}

/**
 * Gets the emf.
 *
 * @return the emf
 */
public EntityManagerFactory getEmf() {
    return emf;
}

/**
 * Sets the emf.
 *
 * @param em the new emf
 */
public void setEmf(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
}

public T findById(Integer id){
    T result = null;
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    if (id == null || id < 1)
        throw new PersistenceException("Id may not be null or negative");
    result = em.find(entityClass, id);
    em.refresh(result);
    em.close();
    return result;
}


@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<T> findAll(){
    List<T> result = null;
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaQuery<Object> cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    result = (List)em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    em.close();
    return result;
}


public void create(T entity){
    System.out.println("Create de AbstractDAO");
    //First we check that the object is not alreadt in database
    List<T> list = findAll();
    if(list.contains(entity)){
        return;
    }
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    if(entity == null)
        throw new PersistenceException("Entity to persist may not be null");//throw Persistence exception
    em.persist(entity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}


public void delete(T entity){
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    if (entity == null)
        throw new PersistenceException("Entity to delete may not be null");
    em.remove(em.merge(entity));
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}


public T update(T entity){
    T result = null;
    if (entity == null){
        System.out.println("Exception : entity to update may not be null");
        throw new PersistenceException("Entity to update may not be null");
    }
    List<T> list = findAll();
    int numberEquals = 0;
    for(T elem : list){
        if(elem.equals(entity))
            numberEquals++;
    }
    if(numberEquals>1)
        return null;
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(entity);
    result = entity;
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return result;
}
```

}

Any help or critics would be much appreciated ! :-)

Comment: How are you removing Analyse and are you maintaining both sides of the bidirectional relationship?  JPA doesn't maintain them - the application must keep both sides in sync.  The Analyse->project relation controls the field in the DB and must be set at a minimum.

Comment: I found my problem : it was actually only happening with the "project" whatever I changed inside one of its dependencies(delete analysis/update a name) because when opening a project I was updating another instance of it (accessible through user.getOpenProjects() )... so it was out of sync. Using a findById to refresh this instance worked for solving the entire problem.

Comment: However, I become more and more aware that I coded something not like I'm supposed to in my DAOs... It works just fine now for all my dependencies (I did a lot of testing) but I think I'm using an alternative way of doing things (and it may not be the advised one...). Through the annotations in my model, all my updates are cascaded the proper way to the rest of the dependencies inside my database and as I always refresh an instance when I send it back to the view (through my "findById"), I do have synchronised relationships. Is that really really bad to use the refresh this way?